# In Illustrator CS6, how do I make my path transparent, but have solid color in the middle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

Basically, I want to have my sketch have a solid color in the inside the path (with live paint), but the path itself that has a stroke, which looks like a border on the image, I want to be completely transparent, so when put on a background you can still see where the border would be, but the background will make it up.

Comment: Do I get your question right that you have drawn a path with a stroke, converted it into a Live Paint object, and now you want to get rid of the stroke?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

With `Live Paint Selection Tool` you can select not only segments of a fill but segments of a stoke as well - just click on a segment of a stroke that you want to get rid of, and then either select a 'None' color, or set stroke width to 0 on the `Stroke` panel.

Comment: This actually doesn't work, or isn't what he (and I) are looking for. When you name the stroke "None" color, or set the stroke width to 0, yes the stroke disappears, but what this person wants (and what I need to do as well) is to have the AREA of the stroke remain, but be invisible. I have been trying to solve this for a long time. Above he says he wants "you can still see where the border would be, but " but the bckground shows through. When you get rid of the stroke, the object seems to sort of "expand" to fill in that space.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to make 2 objects, one with just stroke, and one with just fill.

I was going to suggest making your stroke either black, white or 50% grey, then set it as screen, multiply or overlay respectively to make it invisible over another layer. This will make your solid colors affected by the background however, which is why you may need the stroke & fill to be independent.

Answer (score 0):

The simple truth is for vectors you **create a gap**, and not make a stroke "transparent". In some cases you can simply set the stroke color to match a background color and that is sufficient. A white stroke on a white background *appears* like it's a gap when it's really not.

If you need a gap, then the most likely easy method to create one is to select the shape with the stroke and choose `Object > Expand`. Then select everything and using the **Shape Builder Tool**, <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click the area where the stroke is to remove that shape and create the gap.

It is difficult to provide any further guidance without seeing the actual artwork in question.

Answer (score 0):

Im new to this forum and came upon this question (I was doing some work that needed this effect and this is what worked for me). ((((Duplicate your layers just in case you may need them later before you start!!!)))). Take your vector work and make it 2 colors, so long as the fill is any other color but white, but the stroke however MUST be white for this to work. Select object->Rasterize and rasterize your vector work (there will be a white box around the image but don't worry it'll be gone later. Then select the rasterized object and go to View-> Image Trace. In the image trace menu select MODE to either color or black and white, then check the box "ignore white" and check the preview button. The white strokes should be gone and the colored areas should still be there. Then go to Object->expand. press ok when the fill/stroke menu pops up and voila! Hope this helps.